# Which properties have to match to use the concat remuxer in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I am trying to generate a video to be concated into another video via the ffmpeg concat remuxer. The remux process needs to be extremely efficient for my purposes so I am trying to generate the video in a format that will already be compatible with the original video. However, the original video will not always be in the same format, so the application needs to be able to determine the format information of the original video to be applied to the new video on its own. I know I can retrieve this data with ffprobe, but I am not sure which properties must match for the concat filter to work.

Comment: For all the streams: the codec.
For the audio streams: the sampling rate (44.1kHz, or 48kHz...). For the video streams: the resolution, and if possible the frame rate (it's possible to concat with different frame rates, but you will get less trouble with the same frame rate)

Comment: @PierU thats it? codec, audio sample rate, resolution, and ideally framerate?

Comment: I would say yes, that's it...

Comment: Actually I would add the number of channels and the bit depth for the audio streams, and the bit depth as well for the video streams. The point is that some players will be more tolerant than others if some parameters change during playback.

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603/